# How to refresh the token generated by lambda API using retrofit?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, retrofit2

Currently my login API is done using lambda and the response also contains one token along with it's expiring time. Is there any way like O'Auth token refresh in retrofit for lambda generated token?
Thanks in advance. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no certain API in `Retrofit` to implement this behavior because Retrofit uses `OkHttp` to handle network operations. But you could achieve this by implementing the `Authenticator` interface of the `OkHttp` client that you pass to the Retrofit builder. `OkHttp` call `Authenticator` for `credentials` when the response code is `401` unauthorized error and then retrying to call failed request. 
You could implement the `Authenticator` like so:

```
public class TokenAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    ApiService apiService;

    TokenAuthenticator(ApiService apiService){
        this.apiService = apiService;
    }

    @Override
    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {

        // Refresh your token using a synchronous request
        String newToken = apiService.refreshToken().execute().body();

        // Add new token to the failed request header and retry it
        return response.request().newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", newToken)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And then pass the `TokenAuthenticator` to `OkHttpClient` like this:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient =  new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .authenticator(new TokenAuthenticator(apiService))
        .build();
```

And finally, pass the OkHttpClient to the Retrofit builder:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create an Interceptor that returns to login activity when any request returns 401 to refresh the token

```
public class ErrorInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    Context context;

    public ErrorInterceptor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        // before request
        Request request = chain.request();

        // execute request
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);


        // after request

        // inspect status codes of unsuccessful responses
        switch (response.code()) {
            case 401:
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Login.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);

                // do something else
                Log.e("TEST", "Unauthorized error for: " + request.url());

                // perhaps throw a custom exception ?
                throw new IOException("Unauthorized !!");
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

then you can add the ErrorInterceptor to your OkHttpClient

```
  OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor( new ErrorInterceptor(context))
                .build();
```